# XCode: Arcgis API: displaying multiple feature types of multiple layers in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, arcgis

I am trying to list multiple feature types in multiple layers like how ESRI's ArcGIS application for iPhone does (for different requirements). Each layer would need to form a different section of the table view and all the feature types within that layer would be the elements of that section.

I have been trying to achieve this for about a month now, with no success. :(

Though this is similar to the FeatureLayerEditingSample in ESRI's samples, that displays only one Layer [http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2ddb261648074b9aabb22240b6975918]

I am unsure how to pass the whole dynamic layer (initialized in a map view) to a new table view controller and then display all layers (and the feature types in each layer).

Is there somewhere we can find the source code reference for this or any related tutorials?

This is my first iOS project and I really appreciate any help in this,
Thanks a ton,
Baskaran

Answer (score 1):

Using shapefile directly in your app is difficult. You should convert your shapefile-s to kml and after that use them in your app. It will be way easier to use them as KML (grouping in categories, etc.).

KML is an XML structure (so it's easy to use with NSXmlParser).

You can convert your files with shp2kml ([you can get it here](http://shp2kml.sourceforge.net/))

Comment: hi,thanks. I am using REST services and accessing the featureServices over web. I think we can directly use the URL like "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/FeatureServer/0".

Appreciate any help! thanks